# Can't create child themes. "Stylesheet is not readable."

Tags: child-theme

I'm working on a website for my mom and I'd like to create a child theme to customize the theme I've found for it. I made a new folder in `/wp-content/themes/` and created a new file in it called `style.css`. I copied the code from another website and changed all the details to fit with my template and my new theme. Went back to WordPress and found it listed under **Broken Themes** because **Stylesheet is not readable**.

I checked for spelling, capitalization, and punctuation issues. I make sure the file and folder are in the right places. They are. I pair down the code until it's just the following.

```
/*
Theme Name: theme-child  
Template: theme  
*/
```

Still broken. Okay, fine. Maybe it's the parent theme. So I go and download a different theme, one I don't like as much. Go through the same process to create a child theme for the new theme. That one also shows up as broken because **Stylesheet is not readable**.

What am I doing wrong? I want to do the right thing and customize the child theme instead of the parent, but it's looking like that just isn't an option.

Comment: writing `Template: themeName` means that the _parent theme_ is in `/wp-content/themes/themeName`

Comment: Have you checked out http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes yet? Try to follow along with the example there and see if you can create a basic Twenty Fifteen child theme. If that works, you can apply that code towards your other child theme.

Comment: Have you check that you didn't add space when create folder of child theme or when create style.css? or check permission once.

Answer (score 1):

The template name needs to match exactly the directory name of the parent theme, and you need a functions.php file in the child theme folder.

IE:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Fifteen Child
 Template:     twentyfifteen

*/
```

...or just use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/

and look at the child theme it creates to learn how to do it.